# Play App Deployment on Heroku Failing Due to SASS

Tags: heroku, sass, playframework-2.0, sbt-sass

I am trying to deploy my Play Framework app to Heroku.

Here is the error:

```
remote:        [error] (web-assets:sass) java.lang.Exception: 'sass' command 
not found. Try to add path to 'sass' to your $PATH system variable
```

Doing some research I see there was an issue a few years ago doing this with Ruby - that solution does not seem to fit here.

Do I need to install SASS on Heroku?

Comment: Are you using Sass?  Because you need Sass in order to compile sass.

Comment: @cimmanon i hope thats not an insult :)  ... yes, of course I am using sass, sbt-sass from http://shaggyyeti.github.io/releases.  Everything works fine on my env - this problem is heroku only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to install SASS on Heroku -- it's not there by default.  There two options:

### 1. Use Ruby buildpack

Run these commands:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala
```

Then make sure your project has a Gemfile with these contents:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'sass', '3.4.9'
```

Here is a great example of an app that does this:
https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed

### 2. Use sbt-heroku

This will deploy the locally generate artifacts from your build, so Heroku will not run `sbt compile stage`.:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-scala-and-play-applications-with-the-heroku-sbt-plugin
- https://github.com/heroku/sbt-heroku

Comment: I didn't need the second scala buildpack

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue, deploying a play 2.3.x app to heroku.

I found this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/fzGj5RqW-l8

The solution for me, as mentioned in the thread, was to fork the heroku scala build pack.

Then edit the `bin/compile` file, around line 40 add the following:

`mkdir -p $CACHE_DIR/.gems
gem install -i $CACHE_DIR/.gems --no-rdoc compass
export PATH=$PATH:$CACHE_DIR/.gems/bin
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_PATH:$CACHE_DIR/.gems`

It should be added after the line: `mkdir -p $CACHE_DIR`

Then use the custom build pack:

`heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=url/to/your/custom/build-pack-scala-fork`

After this, you should be able to deploy your app again - and the build should be successful.

Comment: I see the install of Compass but what about SASS?  Is it auto installed as a dep of Compass?  Do I have to install other gems I may be using as well?

Comment: The google forums poster mentioned he was just uploading the binaries.  I am going to try that.

Comment: It installs the compass gem yes, but that is fine for compiling sass.

You could probably just install the sass gem instead. But I have the sass compilling running just fine on heroku, with the sbt-sass and the compass gem installed. 

Personally I don't like the solution, uploading the binaries. So for me the best solutions is to modify the build-pack.